# Strange behaviour with hook_entity_field_access

Tags: 8, hooks

I've implemented hook_entity_field_access like this:

```
function opencase_entity_field_access($operation, \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, $account, $items = NULL) {
  if ($field_definition->getName() == 'field_linked_opencase_actor' && $operation == 'edit') {
    error_log($account->hasPermission('administer users'));
    return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'administer users');
  }
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

When I log is as a user without the "administer users" permission and I go to the edit page containing that field, I get a `'PHP message: \n'`, in the error log showing that the if-block has been reached and that the user does not have the permission. But the field still appears! If I return an `AccessResult::forbidden`, however, it works as expected. Any ideas why `allowedIfHasPermission` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission:](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21AccessResult.php/function/AccessResult%3A%3AallowedIfHasPermission/8.5.x)**

> Creates an allowed access result if the permission is present, neutral
>   otherwise.

If access is allowed somewhere else, a failed check for the permission doesn't prevent access, because it creates a neutral result.

As you found out you probably need to build a forbidden access result.

Comment: Thankyou, this makes perfect sense. I was thinking it meant "if and only if".